# In Field from react-final-form how to convert input value to float only on blur?

Tags: react-final-form

If I use 'parse', then the user can not enter the decimal separator.

Because **"9."** is parsed as **9** and instantly replaces the input text.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xmj92nnpo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I end up with my own StatefulInput component, with 'editing' flag in the internal state. And I call Field's 'onChange' event handler only on blur.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2zpn29zzjj

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. RFF only cares that you respect `value` and `onChange`.

Comment: @ErikR. even this isn't a 100% satisfactory solution because if the field unmounts and remounts later while the value is invalid (for example if it's in an infinite scroll) the invalid value will be lost.  A safer solution would be to use an additional context for storing the raw values/flags.  Would be nice for final-form to support storing a raw value for a field separate from the value that goes to submit.

Comment: Maybe I can store the raw values with final-form-set-field-data?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-final-form-graceful-field

Answer (score 4):

Yep. This is a common problem. If you want to allow decimal points, you have to keep the value as a string, and then convert it to a number at submit time. You can still use `parse` to remove any illegal characters (or `type="number"` on your `<input>`), but you can't parse it into a number on every keypress or you will lose your decimal points.

Comment: @ ErikR - I'm trying to figure out a declarative way to trim() certain string fields for validation and submission, but leave the value in the actual input alone (as, of course, if you can't type spaces at the end of the input you can't have any spaces in the value at all). I thought `parse` might be the way to do this, until I figured out it does actually 'mutate' the input value, not just what's passed to validation/submission. Perhaps it'd be a good idea to state this really clearly in the docs for `parse` with an example (it does say this to be fair, but an example still might help)

Comment: It'd be great if react-final-form provided a way to keep track of the raw data (before parse) and and used that to render the field (ie use `format` only when the value was changed elsewhere e.g. during a form re-init, and otherwise just keep the raw field value) - I think my problem in https://stackoverflow.com/q/70774121/298479 is quite similar, but handling it at submit time is a huge mess unless there's some way to specify transformation logic on the Field level...